# How to let `ls` display the results order in row first?

Tags: ls

I type `ls` in my terminal,

```
A0001  A0004  A0007  A0010  A0015  A0018  A0021  A0024  A0028  A0031  A0034  A0037  A0040  A0043  A0046  A0049  A0052  A0055  A0058  A0061  A0064  A0067
A0002  A0005  A0008  A0013  A0016  A0019  A0022  A0025  A0029  A0032  A0035  A0038  A0041  A0044  A0047  A0050  A0053  A0056  A0059  A0062  A0065  A0068
A0003  A0006  A0009  A0014  A0017  A0020  A0023  A0027  A0030  A0033  A0036  A0039  A0042  A0045  A0048  A0051  A0054  A0057  A0060  A0063  A0066  A0069
```

You see, A0001, A0002, A0003, etc is ordered in the column first then the next column and next. I wang to know how to let the display, have something like,

```
A0001 A0002 A0003 A0004 ....
A0024 A0025 A0026 A0027 ....
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gnu `ls` provides the `-x` option to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `-m` flag, maybe combined with `-T` and/or `-x` (or `-x standalone`).